# How to re-raise pl/sql exception in exception handling block?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I have the following procedure which is used by some applications:

```
procedure p1
is
begin
  bla bla bla;  
end;
```

But there is no exception handling block. So applications were written according this feature.

Now I need to log errors in p1. But it shouldn't affect applications that use this procedure.

Something like this:

```
procedure p1
is
begin
  bla bla bla;

  exception when others then
    log_error(sqlcode, sqlerrm);
    raise_new_exception (sqlcode, sqlerrm);
end;
```

In case of **raise_application_error** first parameter should be in range [-20000, -20999]. So if there raises exception no_data_found, it cannot raise this error.

In case of **exception_init**, second parameter should not be variable. It must be numeric literal.

PS: As temporary solution, I'm using **execute immediate**

Answer (score 35):

If your error stays the same, change to

```
...
exception when others then
  log_error(sqlcode, sqlerrm);
  raise;
end;
/
```

This is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/errors.htm#i3359).

Comment: @AlexPoole Link dead.

Comment: @ceving - thanks, I've put the current live link into the answer instead to it's easier to update in future.

Comment: Current [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm#1049)

Comment: @AlexPoole Link dead again. loshad vtapkah's link works currently.

Comment: @McK - thanks; updated to current 11gR2 version which is what it used to point to (rather than the 9i one loshad linked to).

Comment: Bad thing about raise is that it removes the error backtrace :(

Comment: @Nick Is there any alternative to keep the backtrace also?