# Saving a PL/SQL exception and raising it later?

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, oracle12c

I have a PL/SQL procedure (in an Oracle 12c database) that tries to insert some data. If that fails, it should check a table to see if it can find some info there to help solve the problem. If it finds the information everything is fine, if not it should reraise the error.

This is my code:

```
BEGIN
  -- Try to insert some data.
  INSERT INTO table VALUES x;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN
      -- Check a table to fins some info to help solve the problem.
      -- If we find a row here, we can fix it.
      -- If not, we should reraise the error.
      SELECT * INTO y FROM table WHERE a = b;
      -- Do some more stuff here to fix the problem.
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        -- We could not find anything in the table,
        -- so we could not handle the situation.
        -- Reraise the error.
        RAISE;
    END;
END;
```

The problem here is that the `RAISE;` statement raises the latest exception, which is the `NO_DATA_FOUND` that the `SELECT` statement threw. The original exception from the `INSERT` is further down in the stack, but not at the top.

Can I somehow "save" the error from the `INSERT` and reraise it? Or can I run a `SELECT INTO` that does not throw an error if it finds nothing? My goal here is to reraise the original `INSERT` exception without having any traces of the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception on it.

**EDIT:** See comments as to why this is not a duplicate.

Comment: What could go wrong in the insert and how can you correct it afterwards. Can't you check before it goes wrong?

Comment: I tried to avoid providing to much context in the question to focus on the problem. What I want to do is to do some logging when certain foreign key constraints are violated, and produce custom error messages if that happens. The custom error messages comes from the table, and I do a search on the foreign key constraint that was violated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-raise pl/sql exception in exception handling block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978431/how-to-re-raise-pl-sql-exception-in-exception-handling-block)

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, @Stawros! This is not a duplicate. The solution to the question you suggest is simply use `RAISE`. I already do that, but I want to raise the original error and not the one caused in the exception block.

Comment: You can always retry the insert at the end to let it fail a second time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull the `raise` statement out of the block trying to fix the problem. In case you need to reraise contingent to failure of the fixing, set a flag in the inner exception handler and only execute `raise` when that flag is true.

As code:

```
DECLARE
   b_reraise BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  -- Try to insert some data.
  INSERT INTO table VALUES x;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN
      -- Check a table to fins some info to help solve the problem.
      -- If we find a row here, we can fix it.
      -- If not, we should reraise the error.
      SELECT * INTO y FROM table WHERE a = b;
      -- Do some more stuff here to fix the problem.
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        -- We could not find anything in the table,
        -- so we could not handle the situation.
        -- Reraise the error.
        b_reraise := TRUE;
    END;

    IF b_reraise THEN
        RAISE;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: On a side note, this does not seem to work when I put the part in the outer  `EXCEPTION` into a stored procedure to reuse in other places. Then I can not call `RAISE` from the procedure since it is not in an exception. But it solves my problem for now and the question as I asked it, so accepted answer it is.

Comment: You can always enclose your code by extra `BEGIN..EXCEPTION... END;`, so it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:

```
DECLARE
  l_sqlerrm  VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_sqlerrc  NUMBER;
  l_exc      EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  -- some code with errors
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    l_sqlerrm := SQLERRM;
    l_sqlerrc := SQLCODE;
    -- loggin
    INSERT INTO my_log (code, text) VALUES (l_sqlerrc, l_sqlerrm);
    COMMIT;
    -- some your code "Check a table to fins some info to help solve the problem"
    -- some code to SELECT code INTO l_sqlerrc FROM my_log
    PRAGMA exception_init(l_exc, l_sqlerrc);
    RAISE l_exc;
END;
```

Comment: The second argument of `PRAGMA exception_init` cannot be a variable, so this approach doesn't work, I think.  Interesting idea though.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak hmm... but why it's worked then? CREATE TABLE t1 (ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);
insert into t1 values (1); commit;  DECLARE
  l_sqlerrm  VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_sqlerrc  NUMBER;
  l_tmp      NUMBER;
  l_exc      EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1); 
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    l_sqlerrm := SQLERRM;
    l_sqlerrc := SQLCODE;
    PRAGMA exception_init(l_exc, l_sqlerrc);
    BEGIN    
      SELECT id
        INTO l_tmp
        FROM t1
       WHERE 1 = 2;
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE l_exc;
    END;   
END;

Comment: Attempts to use a variable in the second argument are likely to cause a PLS-00702 error.  Read Oracle's documentation on that error -- it is clear (from that one source) that they do not expect or support a variable in that position, even if it works in your example.  I wouldn't use this for production code without first logging an SR with Oracle to verify it is supported.  Because things that work but aren't supported may not work in later versions.

Comment: I would also point out that your code has the exact same function *without* the PRAGMA.