# Oracle procedure exception that stops rest of procedures

Tags: oracle, exception, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

I want to create a stored procedure that calls stored procedures within it. 
If one of them fails, I want to stop it from executing any of the procedures that would follow after it. Right now, if the first procedure fails, it still is executing procedure 2 and 3. How can I get it to stop doing this?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE run_three_procedures AS 
BEGIN
Package.procedure1;
Package.procedure2;
Package.procedure3;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;

END run_three_procedures;
```

Comment: The current behavior you describe is not normal.  If `procedure1` throws an exception, that should cause the entire procedure to end immediately.  Do the individual procedures have EXCEPTION clauses that prevent exceptions from propagating to the caller?

Comment: @davecosta each procedure says 'exception when others then' and inserts error info into a log table. so when I run the procedure above it says procedure 1 failed, procedure 2 and 3 completed

Comment: see here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978431/how-to-re-raise-pl-sql-exception-in-exception-handling-block/14978649

Answer (score 3):

Per your comment:

> each procedure says 'exception when others then' and inserts error
>   info into a log table. so when I run the procedure above it says
>   procedure 1 failed, procedure 2 and 3 completed

These exception handlers are not allowing the exception to propagate, and there is no way for the calling procedure to know that the called procedure failed.

The two simplest approaches to change this are:

(1) Modify the exception handlers in the called procedures to re-raise the exception:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     /* Do the INSERT into log table */
     RAISE;
```

The unhandled exception would then cause the calling procedure to go to its exception handler, which would execute `ROLLBACK`. Then the procedure would end. The calling procedure would still not report the error, unless you also add `RAISE` in its exception handler.

(2) Change each of the called procedures to a function that returns some indicator of success or failure.  Then you have to make significant changes to the calling procedure to check the return status of each function and decide how to proceed.  I don't recommend this approach; it's basically what exceptions are designed to avoid.

---

By the way, take care with WHEN OTHERS. This will trap literally any exception that could possibly occur while executing the code in Oracle.  Data corruption?  Exception trapped.  Table can't extend?  Exception trapped.  Database in the process of shutting down?  Exception trapped.  Some of these exceptions may imply that the logic in your exception handler won't be able to execute.

Using WHEN OTHERS to trap all exceptions for logging can be useful, but in such a case I would highly recommend always re-raising the exception unless you know that you can recover from it.